# Can't Create VSTO Excel Workbook Project

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, ms-office, vsto

I am having two issues on two computers, I have another question unanswered about opening an existing VTSO Excel workbook.  However this question is about creating a new project with VSTO.  If I select Excel 2013 Workbook C# in new projects, and choose create a new workbook, it starts to open Excel, and then I get this error in VS

[image]

What's really strange is it occurs on two computers I have, with a mix of Office 2010, and Office 2013.  I have installed the lastest R2 and VSTO May release.  Uninstalling & reinstalling VS 2013 made no difference, and switching between R2 and R2 VS made no difference.  Also opening exising projects fails as well.  I read this question and tried the suggested answers, most notably this:

[image]

But to no avail.  I'm at a loss, because I can't work on my project.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: try: right-click your solution and select `Properties`. On the new window navigate the menu on the left and select `Debug`. Then locate `Start External Program` and point it to `Excel.exe`. See if this helps

Comment: That didn't work, on the existing project "Excel designer cannot be activated" error shows up when double clicking sheet1.cs

Comment: As another note, I uninstalled Rebooted and Reinstalled Office 2013 Pro Plus OLP, and I get the same error.  I can see Excel Opening on the task bar, but then the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally stumbled on a solution of sorts for this problem.  I uninstalled Office 2013 x86 and Installed Office 2013 x64, and I also Installed the Visual Studio 2015 RC and I am now able to make new projects.  This doesn't solve everyone's issue, because not everyone can use Office x64, but it works for me.

Comment: That's because it blew away the Office updates that break the VSTO designer.  In time, after updates, I'm sure the problem resurrected.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Dec 22, 2016:

The temporary workaround is to roll-back to a previous version of Excel and disable automatic Office updates.

1. > Open Excel > File > Account > Update Options > Disable Updates
2. > Note of your Office version under Office Updates
3. > Keep reverting to the previous version of Office 2013 / 2016 until issue is resolved:
   >   
   >   Start on Step 2: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2770432

In my case, I went from 6965.**2115** (December 13, 2016) to 6965.**2105** (November 8, 2016)... but issue persisted.

Then down to 6965.**2092** (October 11, 2016).. and **ISSUE RESOLVED!**

### ---

As of Dec. 2016, there's no official Microsoft fix.

Here's the open BUG at Microsoft. Anyone facing this frustration, please up vote to voice your concerns so that Microsoft can take priority on this:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3117015/excel-designer-cannot-be-activated-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

I have been plagued by the "Excel Designer can not be activated" problem, using Visual studio 2015 and 2017, office Addin (VSTO), and have scoured the internet for a solution to no avail.

I have however now got it all working.

I was running Office 2016 32bit version. I uninstalled that and installed the 64bit version and it now works perfectly.

I am not suggesting that there is an issue with the 32bit version. I tried first to uninstall Office 2016 and reinstall, but the problem persisted. I noted others on the net have said that the problem arises by some office configuration issue and sometimes installing new versions fixed this. Clearly uninstalling office 32bit and reinstalling 32bit did not reinstall whatever the configuration was that was corrupt, and so the problem remained.  By installing 64bit version when it previously wasn't installed, a fresh  everything occurred and the problem has gone away. I recognise this doesn't 'fix' the problem, nor does it offer any understanding of what caused the problem. But after days wasted I am back developing again, and that is worth writing about !